# I want change my code from CPP to CUDA, any idea?

Tags: c++, sorting, cuda

I have a problem that i can't solve.

The problem is as follows.

### CPP code

```
const int dataSize = 65535;
const int category = 10;
float data[dataSize][category];
const float threshold = 0.5f;

int cnt = 0;

// data array contains any values

for(int i=0;i<dataSize;i++)
{
    if( data[i][9] > threshold )
    {
        data[cnt][0] = data[i][0];
        data[cnt][1] = data[i][1];
        data[cnt][2] = data[i][2];
        data[cnt][3] = data[i][3];
        data[cnt][4] = data[i][4];
        data[cnt][5] = data[i][5];
        data[cnt][6] = data[i][6];
        data[cnt][7] = data[i][7];
        data[cnt][8] = data[i][8];
        data[cnt][9] = data[i][9];
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

By using this code, I expect 'data' array's element is collected over threshold value.(The element that is not over the threshold is not important to me. Important thing   is just over threshold value.)

I wanna code that operates with same result in CUDA.

So I tried to do like this.

### CUDA code

```
__global__ void checkOverThreshold(float *data, float threshold, int *nCount)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if( data[idx*10+9] > threshold )
    {
        data[nCount+0] = data[idx*10+0];
        data[nCount+1] = data[idx*10+1];
        data[nCount+2] = data[idx*10+2];
        data[nCount+3] = data[idx*10+3];
        data[nCount+4] = data[idx*10+4];
        data[nCount+5] = data[idx*10+5];
        data[nCount+6] = data[idx*10+6];
        data[nCount+7] = data[idx*10+7];
        data[nCount+8] = data[idx*10+8];
        data[nCount+9] = data[idx*10+9];
        atomicAdd( nCount, 1);
    }
}

....

// kernel function call
checkOverThreshold<<< dataSize / 128, 128 >>>(d_data, treshold, d_count);
```

But the result of CUDA code is not that I expected.

It contains lots of trash value and even the result is not the same as CPP's.

I think that the nCount variable's synchronization problem makes this situation.

But, I have no idea to solve this problem.

Please help my code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has a same principle with "Streaming compact"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is broken:

```
    data[nCount+0] = data[idx*10+0];
    data[nCount+1] = data[idx*10+1];
    data[nCount+2] = data[idx*10+2];
    data[nCount+3] = data[idx*10+3];
    data[nCount+4] = data[idx*10+4];
    data[nCount+5] = data[idx*10+5];
    data[nCount+6] = data[idx*10+6];
    data[nCount+7] = data[idx*10+7];
    data[nCount+8] = data[idx*10+8];
    data[nCount+9] = data[idx*10+9];
    atomicAdd( nCount, 1);
```

If `nCount` is modified during all those assignments, nonsense will result. It should be

```
    int d = atomicAdd(nCount, 1);
    data[d+0] = data[idx*10+0];
    data[d+1] = data[idx*10+1];
    data[d+2] = data[idx*10+2];
    data[d+3] = data[idx*10+3];
    data[d+4] = data[idx*10+4];
    data[d+5] = data[idx*10+5];
    data[d+6] = data[idx*10+6];
    data[d+7] = data[idx*10+7];
    data[d+8] = data[idx*10+8];
    data[d+9] = data[idx*10+9];
```

Comment: Thanks david, I'll try to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Stream Compaction functions in the Thrust library.

For example,

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
// ...
const int dataSize = 65535;
struct Datum {
  float f0, f1, f2, ..., f9;
};
Datum data[dataSize];
const float threshold = 0.5f;

struct below_threshold
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const Datum &d)
  {
    return d.f9 <= threshold;
  }
};

// data array is contains any values
Datum *new_end = thrust::remove_if(data, data + N, below_threshold());
int cnt = new_end - data;
// first cnt elements have the f9 term > threshold
// other elements are undefined
```

EDIT: Relevant Thrust documentation [link](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__stream__compaction.html#ga5fa8f86717696de88ab484410b43829b)

If you are unfamiliar with Thrust, here's a quick overview. It's basically a lot of STL style containers and algorithms, plus some Boost-style bells and whistles. The really cool thing is that if you write your algorithm with Thrust instead of cranking out custom kernels, you can actually run the exact same algorithm on either the CPU or GPU. So the implementation sketch I have here would run on the CPU since the memory is allocated in main RAM. But if instead of using a regular array for the data, you use thrust::device_vector (a lot like std::vector), then Thrust would copy your data to the GPU, and the same thrust::remove_if() call paired with the same functor would produce the same result. I hope this gives you a taste for Thrust, and I encourage you to find more on their [quick start guide](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide).

Comment: Let me know if something isn't quite right about this. (I didn't try to compile it, as it's just a sketch.)

I also notice that you tagged your question as sorting. If you're trying to do a quick-sort or something, you'll be happy to find that Thrust has built-in sorts as well.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by SchighSchagh, thrust would be one way to go. ArrayFire provides a more mathematical representation of what is going on.

```
const int dataSize = 65535;
const int category = 10;
float data[dataSize][category];
const float threshold = 0.5f;

int cnt = 0;

// populate data

// Transfer to device
array Data(data, category, dataSize); // Column major
array idx = where(Data(9, span) > threshold);
Data = Data(span, idx);
```

Comment: I hear about ArrayFire recently. That looks pretty cool. I'll try to use it.