# Filtering a list based on a list of booleans

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of values which I need to filter given the values in a list of booleans:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 4, 6]
filter = [True, False, True, False]
```

I generate a new filtered list with the following line:

```
filtered_list = [i for indx,i in enumerate(list_a) if filter[indx] == True]
```

which results in:

```
print filtered_list
[1,4]
```

The line works but looks (to me) a bit overkill and I was wondering if there was a simpler way to achieve the same.

---

### Advices

Summary of two good advices given in the answers below:

1- Don't name a list `filter` like I did because it is a built-in function.

2- Don't compare things to `True` like I did with `if filter[idx]==True..` since it's unnecessary. Just using `if filter[idx]` is enough.

Comment: Just FYI, this is a common parallel computing primitive called [stream compaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089535/17091988#17091988). *(It's called a 'primitive' not because it is simple, but because it's used as a building block for many other parallel algorithms)*

Comment: Some style notes: `if filter[indx] == True` Do *not* use `==` if you want to check for identity with `True`, use `is`. Anyway in this case the whole comparison is useless, you could simply use `if filter[indx]`. Lastly: *never* use the name of a built-in as a variable/module name(I'm referring to the name `filter`). Using something like `included`, so that the `if` reads nicely (`if included[indx]`).

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You're looking for [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 4, 6]
>>> fil = [True, False, True, False]
>>> list(compress(list_a, fil))
[1, 4]
```

### Timing comparisons(py3.x):

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 4, 6]
>>> fil = [True, False, True, False]
>>> %timeit list(compress(list_a, fil))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.58 us per loop
>>> %timeit [i for (i, v) in zip(list_a, fil) if v]  #winner
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 us per loop

>>> list_a = [1, 2, 4, 6]*100
>>> fil = [True, False, True, False]*100
>>> %timeit list(compress(list_a, fil))              #winner
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.3 us per loop
>>> %timeit [i for (i, v) in zip(list_a, fil) if v]
10000 loops, best of 3: 82 us per loop

>>> list_a = [1, 2, 4, 6]*10000
>>> fil = [True, False, True, False]*10000
>>> %timeit list(compress(list_a, fil))              #winner
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [i for (i, v) in zip(list_a, fil) if v] 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.65 ms per loop
```

<sub>Don't use `filter` as a variable name, it is a built-in function.</sub>

Comment: @Mehdi I find the Matlab way highly unintuitive, but I suppose it depends on what you are used to.

Comment: How can I select `[2, 6]` ?

Comment: I get it, `list(compress(list_a, [not i for i in fill]))` should return `[2, 6]`

Comment: `'list' object is not callable`

Answer (score 74):

Like so:

```
filtered_list = [i for (i, v) in zip(list_a, filter) if v]
```

Using `zip` is the *pythonic* way to iterate over multiple sequences in parallel, without needing any indexing. This assumes both sequences have the same length (zip stops after the shortest runs out). Using `itertools` for such a simple case is a bit overkill ...

One thing you do in your example you should really stop doing is comparing things to True, this is usually not necessary. Instead of `if filter[idx]==True: ...`, you can simply write `if filter[idx]: ...`.

Comment: despite this does not have many upvotes, and this is not an accepted solution, why is this answer on the top of the list???

Comment: @Tom check the "sorted by" dropdown list just below the question. You might have it set to "trending (recent votes count more)" or "date modified/created" instead of "highest score"

Comment: ohhh! I see! now I see the option! thank you!

Answer (score 49):

With numpy:

```
In [128]: list_a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 6])
In [129]: filter = np.array([True, False, True, False])
In [130]: list_a[filter]

Out[130]: array([1, 4])
```

or see Alex Szatmary's answer if list_a can be a numpy array but not filter

Numpy usually gives you a big speed boost as well

```
In [133]: list_a = [1, 2, 4, 6]*10000
In [134]: fil = [True, False, True, False]*10000
In [135]: list_a_np = np.array(list_a)
In [136]: fil_np = np.array(fil)

In [139]: %timeit list(itertools.compress(list_a, fil))
1000 loops, best of 3: 625 us per loop

In [140]: %timeit list_a_np[fil_np]
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 us per loop
```

Comment: Good point, I prefer using `NumPy` over `list` where possible. But if you need to use `list` anyway, you have (using `NumPy` solution) create `np.array` from both lists, use boolean indexing and finally converting array back to list with `tolist()` method. To be precise, you should include those objects creation into time comparison. Then, using `itertools.compress` will be still the fastest solution.

Answer (score 21):

To do this using numpy, ie, if you have an array, `a`, instead of `list_a`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 6])
my_filter = np.array([True, False, True, False], dtype=bool)
a[my_filter]
> array([1, 4])
```

Comment: If you turn my_filter into a boolean array, you can use direct boolean indexing, without the need for `where`.

Answer (score 7):

```
filtered_list = [list_a[i] for i in range(len(list_a)) if filter[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be not so elegant, but I think this solution has simplier syntax. I renamed `filter` to `filter_` to avoid conflict with the built in function:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 4, 6]
filter_ = [True, False, True, False]
```

Here the solution:

```
index = [i for i in range(len(filter_)) if filter_[i]]
list_a_filtered = [list_a[i] for i in index]
```

or in one line:

```
list_a_filtered = [list_a[i] for i in [j for j in range(len(filter_)) if filter_[j]]]
```

Answer (score -4):

With python 3 you can use `list_a[filter]` to get `True` values. To get `False` values use `list_a[~filter]`

Comment: With e.g. `numpy.array`, this works, but with built-in lists it doesn’t.

Comment: What happens when you try this with a list?