# Selection elements of a list based on another 'True'/'False' list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of the same length.
The first one contains strings. The second one - strings that can be either `'True'` or `'False'`.

If the nth element of the second list is `'True'`, I want to append the nth element of the first list to another list.

So if I have:

**List1:**

```
('sth1','sth2','sth3','sth4')
```

**List2:**

`('True','False','True','False')`

The outcome should be **List3**:

`('sth1','sth3')`.

How can I intersect two list in that way?

Comment: FWIW, this would be cleaner if `List2` contained Python's boolean values `False` & `True` rather than strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a list based on a list of booleans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665873/filtering-a-list-based-on-a-list-of-booleans) (assuming those strings are really booleans)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use zip:

```
result = [x for x, y in zip(xs, ys) if y == 'True']
```

Example:

```
xs = ('sth1','sth2','sth3','sth4')
ys = ('True','False','True','False')
result = [x for x, y in zip(xs, ys) if y == 'True']
result
['sth1', 'sth3']
```

Comment: Instead of "...if y == 'True'" you can simple use "...if y"

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your comment. 'True' (string) is not the same as True (boolean). Or rather more importantly - 'False' is truth-y. Just try `bool('False')`. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right.  Somehow I copied down the quotation marks without my brain taking in the fact that they're strings!

Answer (score 12):

Or use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
filtered = np.array(List1)[np.array(List2)]
```

Btw this only works if the elements inside List2 are True/False, not if they are "True"/"False".

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't know about `zip` :

```
l1 = ('sth1','sth2','sth3','sth4')
l2 = ('True','False','True','False')
l = [x for i,x in enumerate(l1) if l2[i]=='True']
print l
#=> ['sth1', 'sth3']
```

It would be shorter with a tuple of booleans :

```
l1 = ('sth1','sth2','sth3','sth4')
l2 = (True,False,True,False)

l = [x for i,x in enumerate(l1) if l2[i]]
print l
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to use **`itertools.compress`** method as follows.

```
import itertools

list1 = ('sth1','sth2','sth3','sth4')
list2 = ('True','False','True','False')
list2 = map(lambda x: x == 'True', list2)

result = list(itertools.compress(list1, list2))
```

`compress` method returns an iterator, so you that is why you need to wrap the iterator object in `list`

I hope it helps.