# Toggling between two sets of boolean and string representations

Tags: python, string, if-statement, boolean, combinations

I have 2 boolean variables:

```
a = True
b = True
```

and each one has some properties that manifests in their string representations:

```
a_str = "a is real"
b_str = "b is surreal"
```

And the results should:

- Check if `a and b` is True, is so, output "**a is real AND b is surreal**"
- Check if only `a` is True, then output: "**a is real**"
- Check if only `b` is True, then output: "**b is surreal**"

I've tried the following and it works but eliciting the different if-elifs is rather verbose, i.e.

```
a = True
b = True

a_str = "a is real"
b_str = "b is surreal"

if a and b:
    print(f"{a_str} AND {b_str}")
elif a:
    print(a_str)
elif b:
    print(b_str)
```

esp. if there's a new variable `c`, e.g.

```
a = True
b = True
c = True

a_str = "a is real"
b_str = "b is surreal"
c_str = "c is cereal"

if a and b and c:
    print(f"{a_str} AND {b_str} AND {c_str")
elif a and b:
     print(f"{a_str} AND {b_str}")
elif a and c:
     print(f"{a_str} AND {b_str}")
elif b and c:
     print(f"{b_str} AND {c_str}")
elif a:
     print(a_str)
elif b:
     print(b_str)
elif c:
     print(c_str)
```

Is there a cleaner way to enumerate the different cases for the boolean checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you do something like:

```
' AND '.join(filter(None,[a_str*a,b_str*b,c_str*c]))
```

Comment: Elegant solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have those values in a two different list. One with boolean and the other one with string to print.

Then you can have same logic as this post described to get a third list which have values with index True: [Selection elements of a list based on another 'True'/'False' list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762592/selection-elements-of-a-list-based-on-another-true-false-list)

Now join the third list with "and".