# How do I create a list from one list of integers and one list of booleans? (Python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

e.g. suppose I have two lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [False,True,False,True,False,False]
```

How can i create the list below (only using items in list1 that correspond to false in list2 by index position?

```
list3 = [1,3,5,6]
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a list based on a list of booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665873/filtering-a-list-based-on-a-list-of-booleans)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.zip`

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [False,True,False,True,False,False]
list3=[j for i,j in zip(list2,list1) if i==False]
print(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [False,True,False,True,False,False]
list3=[]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    if list2[i] == False:
        list3.append(list1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Boolean Logic and list comprehensions:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [False,True,False,True,False,False]
print([i[0] for i in zip(list1,list2) if not i[1]])    # this just includes an element if that element's corresponding value in the second list is False
```

This outputs:

```py
[1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [False,True,False,True,False,False]

list3=[]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list2[i]==False:
        list3.append(list1[i])
```

Comment: Your code has error. You are iterating over the list, so the index can go out of bounds as 6 index is actually 7th one. Also, ```list1(i)```,this is wrong

Comment: This is identical to Mukul Kumar's earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [False,True,False,True,False,False]
output = list (map (lambda x,y: x if y == False else '', list1,list2))
while '' in output:
    output.remove('')
print(output)
```

Outputs
[1, 3, 5, 6]